# How can I write a bash script that pulls all of the http://whatever.com/something out of a file

Tags: linux, bash, gnu, wget

I am migrating a site in PHP and someone has hardcoded all the links into a function call display image('http://whatever.com/images/xyz.jpg').

I can easily use text mate to convert all of these to http://whatever.com/images/xyz.jpg.

But what I also need to do is bring the images down with it so for example `wget -i images.txt`.

But I need to write a bash script to compile images.txt with all the links to save me doing this manually because there are a lot!

Any help you can give on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you want us to do it or you want us to help you with a problem while you were doing it ?

Comment: I need documentation or a place to start or a tutorial on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a one-liner on [that website](http://scripts-n-codes.blogspot.com/2010/01/bash-extract-links-from-file-and.html) that should work: (replace index.php by your source)

```
wget `cat index.php | grep -P -o 'http:(\.|-|\/|\w)*\.(gif|jpg|png|bmp)'`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you `wget` the file via. a web server, will you not get the output from the PHP script? That will contain `img` tags which you can extract using `xml_grep` or some such tool.

Comment: Like I said Up there ^^ I can use textmate to to find and replace the php locations, this is is not a problem. I need to rip the images from it first and then find and replace.

Comment: MAybe I need to rephrase myself. Will you have programmatic access to a processed file (i.e. HTML) or only the PHP source?

Comment: I have the php source files yes.

Comment: Then run `php` on the source (either using the command line or via. a web server), get the output HTML and then use `xml_grep` to extract all the `img` tags and then wget all of them. This can be done by a shell one liner. The actual solution is left as an exercise to the reader. :)